# Java - jar - consuming compiled class which extends another class - 'this' reference is null

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, this, executable-jar

Consuming a compiled class (which extends another class) from a jar, the methods from parent class methods are added with 'this.' which is throwing null pointer while consuming those methods ('this' became null)

The methods from the parent's class in the base class (in the jar - compiled classes) should be able to consume without null pointer error for 'this' reference

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the stack trace. As far as I know, it's impossible for `this` to ever be `null`.

Comment: "`this` became null": no it didn't. It's impossible.